# I am developing a hexadecimal to decimal converter

Tags: java

The **output** of my program should be in the **text** **variable** but it **does not work**.
Please help me, it is for a **school competition**. When I give it for ex.:AE2362 it **simply prints** **nothing**(value that I **declared before** to it).

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] g =  new String[6];
        String abc = "ABCDEF";
        for(int  i =0; i<= g.length-1;i++) {
                char c = abc.charAt(i);
                g[i] =  String.valueOf(c);

        }
        Scanner sc =  new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a hexadecimal code:");
        String inp = sc.nextLine();
        sc.close();
        String text ="";
        for(int i =0;i<=inp.length()-1;i++) {
            char c2 = inp.charAt(i);
            for(int h =0;h<=g.length-1;h++) {   
                if(String.valueOf(c2)==g[h]) {
                    text += String.valueOf(h+10);
                }
            }
            if(Integer.valueOf(c2)>=0&&Integer.valueOf(c2)<=9) {
                text += String.valueOf(c2);
            }   
        }
        System.out.println(text);

    }

}
```

Comment: You're using `==` to compare two `String`s.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

check this [solution](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/31datatype/Hex2Decimal.java.html) if you are going to develop it yourself. if fact it is already developed, you don't have to invent one.

```
String hexValue = "put your hex in quotes";
int decimalValue = Integer.parseInt(hexValue, 16);
```

Hope it will help

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think the OP is doing an assignment where they have to do the hex conversion manually, not use a built-in method. Also, your answer does not address the big problem of using `==` to compare String values. That could be dangerous both for the OP and for future readers. (BTW, when you answer a heavily downvoted question there's a risk that your answer will also attract downvotes too).

Comment: @PM2Ring that's why i provided solution link,  where is shown how to convert hex manually. the rest is correct remarks. i have not noticed that he is comparing strings with ==.

Comment: **1** Ok, the link is useful, although the Stack Exchange policy is that links should *enhance* the post, and you should copy the key info from the link into your post. **2** See `if(String.valueOf(c2)==g[h])` in the OP's code.

Comment: 1. i will have it in mind. 2. yes i saw it just now, when you mentioned it in first comment. Thanks